# How to stop XSD designer from prefixing database names to tables in XSD codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, xsd

In an ASP.NEt application we have an XSD file and a web.config file.

Within the config file we have the connection strings specified like this:

```
<add name="DbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=sqldb;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and within the XSD codebehind we have the following lines (auto generated) for each table adapter select command:

```
<DbSource ConnectionRef="DbConnectionString (Web.config)" DbObjectName="dbo.CUSTOMER" ...
```

However if I open the table adapter query in the designer and modify the SQL then the line in the code behind gets changed to this:

```
<DbSource ConnectionRef="DbConnectionString (Web.config)" DbObjectName="TestDb.dbo.CUSTOMER" ...
```

It adds the 'TestDb' at the beginning of the table name specified in DbObjectName.

Obviously this would be wrong when we publish this website to the live system as it would try to get
the data from the TestDB even if we change the connection string to 'LiveDb' in web.config.

Has anyone encountered this behaviour and is there a way of stopping the XSD designer to stop from prefixing database name to tables?

Thanks

Comment: can you share your connectionstring specified in webonfg...

Comment: I have updated the question with it.

Answer (score 1):

its happening when you add tables from different databases to the dataset. While adding tables or queries to the dataset dont fetch different database or connection strings. Please check all your tables added to the dataset. then recreate the tables which has the same issues to the current dataset. Dont change the connection name while adding the dataset tables. use the same connection string specified in the web config.

thanks